# C - reset stdin after reading from file

Tags: c, shell, unix, stdin, eof

I'm building a (very) minimal Unix shell, and I'm having some trouble resetting the input stream when a configuration file is provided. When the file is provided, my shell reads from the file until it reaches the EOF, as it should. At that point, I want to read input from stdin. However, my command parser functions such that it terminates when EOF is reached, so the shell fails to continue running once the configuration file is processed. I'd appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

EDIT: code for reference

```
while ((pcLine = readLine(pfInput)) != NULL)
{   
  oTokens = findTokens(pcLine);
  if (oTokens != NULL)
  {  
     /* Print command from configuration file. */
     if (argc >= 2)
        printf("%s\n", pcLine);
     oCommand = newCommand(oTokens);
     if (oCommand != NULL)
     {  
        pcName = command_getName(oCommand);
        if (strcmp(pcName, "setenv") == 0)
           ish_setEnv(oCommand);
        else if (strcmp(pcName, "unsetenv") == 0)
           ish_unsetEnv(oCommand);
        else if (strcmp(pcName, "cd") == 0)
           ish_cd(oCommand);
        else if (strcmp(pcName, "exit") == 0)
           ish_exit(oCommand);
        else 
           execute(oCommand);

        freeCommand(oCommand);
     }
  }

  free(pcLine);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your command parser code?

Comment: I'd rather not, only because a piece of it features code I didn't write. What I can say is that my code goes through 4 steps: 1) it reads a line from the designated stream; 2) it breaks down the line into tokens; 3) the tokens are then used to form a command; 4) the command is executed.

The problem code is in the first step. The readLine() method returns NULL when it reaches EOF: (see above).

Comment: The problem, then, involves reassigning pfInput (see above) to stdin once the configuration file is processed, and then continuing in the while loop.

Comment: I fixed the problem using a goto statement, which I'd prefer not to use. Any alternatives suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It's very difficult (bordering on impossible) to suggest anything without seeing actual code. It's still not even clear to me what the original problem was. This is required reading in order to get help on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve